# Edge loop is acting like a Seam when I unwrap UV

Tags: uv

I made seams at the top and bottom edges of the cup but when I unwrap my image it gets cut by an edge loop in the middle of the cup. When I try deleting the edge loop it deletes the whole structure of the cup. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: What method are you using to unwrap it? Do you know what Edge Collapse is? and are you moving the Edge Loop after applying the texture? Ctrl [E] Clear Seam would indeed remove edges from being marked as seams if that's what happened. I wonder if there's something else going on here....

Comment: I selected every face I wanted mapped within the seams ( Ctrl L ) and went to ( U > Unwrap ) and that fixed the issue. Thanks anyways!